# Firefox does not keep cookies sent by cross-domain even with all CORS allow

Tags: firefox, cookies, cors, cross-domain

I experience a problem with Firefox while Chrome works fine. Here is the situation:

- Website1.com returns an html page in SSL.
- This page makes a request to Website2.com in SSL either via img tag or XMLHttpRequest (same issue).
- Website2.com returns a cookie to be set for itself
- Firefox ignores this cookie. It is never stored even though it shows in the console.
- The console doesn't complain about anything.

Client sends:

```
Origin: https://website1.com
```

Server returns:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://website1.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
Set-Cookie: ...
```

What else am I missing about CORS?

Thanks!

Comment: did you found an answer?  I have the same issue, everything works on chrome and ie ... but firefox is not sending the cookie.

Comment: maybe it is related to your browser settings, reset the firefox.

Comment: Hey , Is Accept Third party cookies and data enabled in your firefox?

Comment: Yes, it's accepting, and settings are set to default. I tried it in different computers using standart and developer editions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Is a special flag. If one side declares it other also have to declare it or else it's security failure and browser will not accept data.

So add the same header to client request. (Or if you control server, consider doing without cookies and passing data with other mechanism)